# Angular Directive on Binded Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to make a text formatting Directive in Angular.

In my current application i have many places where i have to present time in HH:MM:SS format, the time in the DB is saved in seconds. So i was thinking that maybe a directive would be the right thing here.
For example: everywhere i want to present time in HH:MM:SS i just add the directive "showAsTime" to the element containing the time in seconds.

**Q1** What would be the best approach here?

*Only part of the code, shown:*

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="time in timeList">
        <td data-show-as-time>{{ time.rowTime }}</td> //time in seconds
    <tr>
</table>
```

*The problem is that i dont get the value, the directive is executed first, if i "hardcode" a value say: 900 in place of {{ time.rowTime }} i get the correct presentation "00:15:00".*

**Q2** In one part of the application i have a model bound to a counter as shown below. 
Is it possible to make the same Directive work even here?

*Only part of the code, shown:*

```
<h1 data-ng-model="timeCounter" data-show-as-time>{{timeCounter}}</h1>

//timeCounter adds 1 to timeCounter every second (with a $interval in the controller).
```

Time calculations is done as follows,

*time.js*

```
app.factory('time',function(){

    var timeFactory = {};

    timeFactory.timeFromSeconds = function(seconds){
        var timeFromSeconds     
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds/3600);

        if(hours > 0) minutes = minutes - hours * 60;

        seconds = seconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;

        if(hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
        if(minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        if(seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;

        timeFromSeconds = hours +":"+minutes+":" + seconds;

        return timeFromSeconds;
    }

 return timeFactory;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the date filter stated in the other answer (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), you could also implement a custom filter to further format your model data:

```
angular.filter('doSomething', function() {
    return function(input) {
        //do something on your input and return it
    }
  })
```

In your html, then, you can call your filter as

```
{{model|doSomething}}
```

This is probably the best way to obtain the behavior you want, rather than using a directive.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer because it gives both explanation of the filter and how to create custom filters. If it also described the standard implementation as {{ time.timeRow * 1000 | date:"HH:mm:ss" }} it would be perfect. Even if @MDiesel also gave the right answer, I think this can help more people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a date filter in Angular that can do this for you.

Check the link out here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Note that the date filter expects time in milliseconds, so the OP will have to do "{{time.rowTime*1000|date}}"